# How to change the src of an iframe to an embed src within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, embed

This may sound a bit confusing at first but I will try to explain. I am trying to access the code of an embed tag playing a youtube video inside an iframe and have it change the src on an outside iframe when the inner embed container is clicked.

note:the external frame is a full website in the background of the myframe player. myframe is a mock video player.

heres the basic way the document is set up

```
<body>
<iframe id='myframe' src='something.htm'></iframe>
<iframe id='externalFrame' src='external.htm'></iframe>
</body>

//external.htm
<body>
<embed id='mediaPlayer' src='somethingElse.htm' >
</body>
```

**external javascript**

```
var myPlayer=document.getElementById('myframe');
var externalFrame=document.getElementById('externalFrame');
externalFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('mediaPlayer').onclick=function(){
var mediaPlayer=externalFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('media_player'); 
myPlayer.src=mediaPlayer.src;
}
```

For the record I hate iframes with the passion of 1000 suns, and would never use them usually but for this the media player has to keep playing when the page changes. and Iframes are good for mimicking that.

Comment: What is your question exactly what doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

That should work fine just make sure that the link to the src is directed to the correct place in the structure.